# Select last cell in column then increment value by 1

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a SQL data table in my program and I am trying to **select** the **last value** in a column.

Then in my form use the **next number**.

So for example column is part number abc-00001 and when I launch a new form it **automatically** places abc-00002 into a text box.

```
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader

        cmd.CommandText = "select prtnum FROM Table1 WHERE prtnum = IDENT_CURRENT('table1')"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = con

        con.Open()

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        textbox1.text = prtnum (increment 1)
```

Comment: Are all part numbers in the format abc-00000?

Comment: Can you maybe explain a little better what you are trying to achieve? Where is the next part number coming from?

Comment: yeah all the part numbers will be abc-0001, then abc 00002, the next part number will always be digit more than the last row.

Comment: IDENT_CURRENT gives you the last identity number generated for the table -- these are integers not alphanumeric.  Please post the DDL for table1 and exactly what you are trying to do so we can answer this question.

Comment: @GeordieOz Do you have any auto increment column in that table ???

Comment: just try this `SELECT TOP 1 prtnum FROM Table1
ORDER BY prtnum DESC;`.For the correct answer you must provide `Table1`'s DDL(_create table_),

Answer (score 0):

You should have use Sequences to generate part number.

for example,

CREATE SEQUENCE seq_PartNumber
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10

**INSERT:**
INSERT INTO Table1(prtnum)
VALUES (seq_PartNumber.nextval)

**SELECT:**
SELECT seq_PartNumber.nextval FROM Table1

Please check following link,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create a query that returns the maximum value of your field. For example,  "SELECT Max(Field) AS MaxValue From Table", assign it to a variable and then increment it by 1, but you have to do some conversions and formats before you see  the desired result. Below is an example of what you can do:

```
    Dim connStr As String
    connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data      Source=C:\Users\Juan\Documents\LastValueDatabase.accdb;
    Persist Security Info=False;"
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT Max(Code) AS MaxValue
    From LastValue"

    Dim connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connStr)

    Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
    connection.Open()
    Dim newCode As String = ""
    newCode = command.ExecuteScalar()
    Dim maxValue As Integer
    Dim code As String = ""

    For Each value As Char In newCode
        If IsNumeric(value) Then
            maxValue &= value
        Else
            code &= value
        End If

    Next
    maxValue = Integer.Parse(maxValue) + 1
    TextBox1.Text = code & maxValue.ToString("00000")

    connection.Close()
```

I used Microsoft Access for this example but you can do it with SQL, you only have to change the connection strings and instead of Oledb use Sql connecion.